# WCF service - Getting Runtime error in basicHttpBinding configuration transport clientCredentialType to Basic

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I have created a web service and I am using basicHttpBinding but the thing is when I set the  clientCredentialType to None I can able to access the service but if I set to Basic/Windows I am getting error like "Runtime error".In IIS basic authentication is used. I need security for basicHttpbinding. How to resolve this issue.

**Code in Web.Config:**

```
<services>
      <service name="HealthCareService" behaviorConfiguration="Behavior_Service1">
        <endpoint address="" contract="IHealthCareService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding1"  />
<endpoint address="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBinding1">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Behavior_Service1">
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions="10000"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

**Error Screen shot:**
[image]

Comment: First off, do as the error page suggests and set <customErrors mode="Off"/>. This will display the base exception and stack trace. Get those and post them.

Comment: @simonatrcl  500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.  Displayed after custom mode set to off

Comment: @my1 - Take a look at the event viewer to see if anything was logged there.  Most likely your service is throwing an exception that is not being handled.

Comment: Show us your url, also tell us how you host the service? is it IIS? IIS express? or self hosting?  Also show your full web.config, as i don't see your base address or service activations. And finally, what .net framework version are you using?

Comment: @Roman I am getting this error when I am setting the clientCredentialType to basic but in IIS basic authentication is enabled. When I set clientCredentialType to None i can able to access the service.

Comment: Can you post another screenshot with the actual error? and please provide all requested information like url, web.config, .net version.

Comment: Check the servers', Event log if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Enable tracing on the WCF server  [as described in this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx).  The trace should give you enough info to troubleshoot the problem.

If it works with clientCredentialType = None, perhaps your client is not configured correctly - the configuration of client and server need to be compatible.